# Spark: group only part of the rows in a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

From a given DataFrame, I'dl like to group only few rows together, and keep the other rows in the same dataframe.

My current solution is:

```
val aggregated = mydf.filter(col("check").equalTo("do_aggregate")).groupBy(...).agg()
val finalDF = aggregated.unionByName(mydf.filter(col("check").notEqual("do_aggregate")))
```

However I'd like to find a more eleguant and performant way.

Comment: Did you manage to execute this and do df.show?

Comment: this could be done window-functions, but you should show a concrete example first

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived column to group by, depending on the check.

```
mydf.groupBy(when(col("check").equalTo("do_aggregate"), ...).otherwise(monotonically_increasing_id)).agg(...)
```

If you have a unique key in the dataframe, use that instead of `monotonically_increasing_id`.